# How to make a table from specific range in an array

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to make a table of values from some data in the middle of an array of data. As seen bellow:

```
x = Range[5]
StandardQuickSort = {96033 , 156879 , 3538056 , 13935883 , 30104396 , 
  89097 , 170994 , 7567432 , 34201637 , 83379287 , 99552 , 240557 , 
  14280676 , 65793563 , 161368440 , 92616 , 117797 , 565056 , 
  1155717 , 1759517 , 91086 , 125328 , 1830106 , 65249229 , 152515649}

standardDesc = 
 Table[{x[[i]], StandardQuickSort[[i]]}, {i, 6, Length[x]}]
```

so that it should look like this:

```
{{1, 89097 }, {2, 170994 }, {3, 7567432 }, {4, 34201637 }, {5, 83379287 }}
```

What i tried above does not work, any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, your indexing in Table is problematic. If you look at the documentation for the Table command, you'll see that when you pass three values to Table for the range, it interprets it as:

`{i,i_min,i_max}`

so in your case this would be "Take i from 6 to 5", hence you have no output in your table.

One way you can accomplish what you're looking for is to specify the Min-Max like you already are:

`standardDesc = Table[{x[[i]],StandardQuickSort[[i]]},{i,6,6+Length[x]}]`

However, this will ruin your indexing (which I assume is important to you. If you know that you're always going to take the same positions in your quicksort, I would use this clunky solution:

`standardDesc = Table[{x[[i-5]],StandardQuickSort[[i]]},{i,6,5+Length[x]}]`

This gives your desired output.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, works perfect!

Comment: No problem. If you need a general solution, and you're not too concerned with performance, I would consider using the ```Do``` command, and the ```AppendTo``` command. I've used those frequently for this type of application.

Answer (score 1):

A more functional solution

```
Transpose[{x, StandardQuickSort[[6 ;; 6 + Length@x - 1]]}]
(* {{1, 89097}, {2, 170994}, {3, 7567432}, {4, 34201637}, {5, 83379287}} *)
```